# Custom Option to add a fixed price

Tags: price, custom-options, custom-prices

I run a silent disco company.

I want people to hire headphones from my website in any quantity.

I want people to select between a 2 channel and 3 channel option.
I want the 3 channel option to add £39.99 to the total price.

E.g. - somebody books 100 headphones at £1 per headphone = £100.
Somebody books 100 headphones with 3 channels at £1 per headphone = £139.99.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

That's a default feature of Magento, just add a custom option with an input type of Select, Drop-down or Radio-Buttons. Then add two items: 2 channel would be zero price and 3 channel would be the additional 39.99

Comment: And that 39.99 doesn't get multiplied by the quantity?

Answer (score 0):

I am looking for exact the same answer. My searching so far didn't got me further then the need for an extension (http://www.absolutepricing.com/). However there is a free workaround possible. You could create a price rule based on sku for the particular product. Then install an extension what allows surcharges with price rules (easily to find with google) and you are done. It is not an elegant solution but might be adequate for you. I will check this thread to see if there is a better solution.

regards